# When I create an object, is fresh memory allocated to both instance fields and methods or only to instance fields

Tags: java, object-oriented, memory, jvm

I have a following class

```
class Student{

int rollNumber;
int marks;

public void setResult(int rollNumber, int marks){

    this.rollNumber=rollNumber;
    this.marks=marks;   
}

public void displayResult(){

    System.out.println("Roll Number= "+this.rollNumber+"   Marks= "+this.marks);

}
}
```

Now I create two objects of type Student as follows

```
Student s1=new Student();
Student s2=new Student();
```

Now two different sets of memory is allocated for instance fields. Now my question is whether memory is allocated for methods (`setResult` and `displayResult`) twice or once?

Please see the following figure and can you help me saying which figure gives correct information.

[image]

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'am learning java...and in all the materials they just say that whenever we create an object a fresh memory is allocated to all the instance fields..but, none of the materials said whether fresh memory will be allocated for methods or not

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code for methods is part of the `Class` (more concisely, `Class<Student>`) and it is loaded into memory when the class is first loaded.

That said, when you execute any method additional memory is used, to allocate memory to parameters, local variables, temporary expression results, return values and so on. But such memory is allocated in **the stack** (the memory used when creating a new instance is allocated in **the heap**.

As per your question, it should be clear now that figure B is correct (although it does not reflect what happens when you actually call the method).

Comment: Ok. I'am 90% clear now....But a small doubt..  Suppose if i create a 10 objects of type Student then only 1 set of fresh memory is allocated to the methods present in class Student whereas 10 sets of fresh memory is allocated to store instance variables for 10 objects..Am i right?

Comment: Right. Think that it is not only the properties that take memory, there is a small overhead related to the instance itself (an instance of a class with no properties will use more than 0 bytes of memory).

Comment: One more thing... I asked question keeping java in mind....Does the same thing happens in java.....

Comment: The Java Language Specification doesn't say anything about how much memory is allocated when and for what purpose. That is left to the implementer, and every implementer may choose differently.

Answer (score 6):

Instance fields (including property backing fields) get N-copies for N-objects.

Static fields get a single copy per class.

Methods are blocks of bytecode (or after JIT, blocks of native instructions) that are part of the program "image" or executable code segment. Methods are already part of the program image as it sits on disk. Once the image is loaded by the OS (or CLR), there is a single shared copy of the method code.

They aren't part of "heap" or runtime allocation in general, except in cases where you may use the hostable compiler to compile new methods on the fly. Methods don't get "allocated" like objects and they aren't "allocated" relative to the object creation. They merely exist as part of the program before a single object is ever instantiated. Even lambdas / delegates aren't allocated on the fly. The compiler creates classes on-demand to implement these other seemingly dynamic code objects, and they also exist as part of the bytecode image on disk.

UPDATES per comments:

The JVM standard has this to say:

> **2.5.4. Method Area**
>
> The Java Virtual Machine has a method area that is shared among all
>   Java Virtual Machine threads. The method area is analogous to the
>   storage area for compiled code of a conventional language or analogous
>   to the "text" segment in an operating system process. It stores
>   per-class structures such as the run-time constant pool, field and
>   method data, and the code for methods and constructors, including the
>   special methods (§2.9) used in class and instance initialization and
>   interface initialization.
>
> The method area is created on virtual machine start-up. Although the
>   method area is logically part of the heap, simple implementations may
>   choose not to either garbage collect or compact it. This version of
>   the Java Virtual Machine specification does not mandate the location
>   of the method area or the policies used to manage compiled code. The
>   method area may be of a fixed size or may be expanded as required by
>   the computation and may be contracted if a larger method area becomes
>   unnecessary. The memory for the method area does not need to be
>   contiguous.

So it is clear that (1) yes the spec does not dictate how this is done, but (2) it is analogous to the storage area for compiled code of a conventional language, ie. the text segment. This is the point I'm making.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, but is that actually guaranteed by the JLS? Normally, the JLS gives implementors a *lot* of leeway in questions like this.

Comment: Not sure on that point, @JörgWMittag. You may be right. The point I tried to make is "new T()" doesn't allocate a new instance of a method. As to the specifics of the JVM, classloaders do indeed store bytecode in the heap, and I guess there are possible scenarios where classes themselves are instantiated and even garbage collected. But it is implementation detail of the runtime, and conceptually, the heap I'm talking about is the "user" heap. The class & methods are not considered data in the normal user context. But since we can also control a classloader from userland, I guess I don't know.

Comment: The JLS doesn't even talk about a heap at all, doesn't it? It's perfectly legal to implement Java with a dynamic stack and no heap instead of a finite fixed-size stack and a dynamic heap. The JLS also doesn't say anything about the JVM, it's perfectly valid to implement Java without a JVM.

Comment: You are referencing JLS, but I'm talking JVM. The JVM standard certainly discusses heap. You must provide a variable scope/lifetime that escapes the local scope of the stack. As to what is theoretically possible, I prefer to think in terms of "known implementations". I'm pretty sure implementing a full JVM without a heap primitive is a tough, or even impossible, job since the JVM isn't a pure stack machine. My understanding of the Forth machines, and other pure stack architectures, are that it may be possible if a primitive exists for random variable access, but I just haven't seen it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I added to the answer something that may be of interest for our discussion. The point is I was drawing an analogy to the traditional code or text segment in conventional runtime systems.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the [tag:jvm] tag on the question. I usually tend to think of the two as completely separate, because I actually do use Java and I do use the JVM, but I have never used the two together: I pretty much exclusively use Java without the JVM (on Android) and the JVM without Java (using Scala and JRuby).

Comment: I understand. The prevalence of VM / Interpreter runtime environments has made many traditional computer science statements "subjective" because of implementation detail, however, I still like to use traditional terms for traditional concepts and often don't qualify my statements with a list of caveats based on these details.

Comment: Also, modern compiler optimizations. Escape Analysis can move objects with heap semantics to the stack, stream fusion, list fusion, array fusion and the likes can make it so that an object that is allocated *semantically* on the heap is in fact completely eliminated and not allocated *at all*. TCO can change the space complexity. Supercompilation may in rare cases even change the algorithmic complexity! Eric Lippert has a nice blog post where he attacks the "`struct`s are on the stack, `class`es are on the heap" notion and says that what matters is the semantics. Stack and heap are incidental.

Answer (score -4):

object allocated in heap memory.when object are allocated the slot for all the instance variable is created and destroyed when the object are destroyed.so instance variable is also allocated in heap memory.And the local variable are created in stack at the time when the method are called.

Comment: This appears to just repeat information that is provided in earlier answers.